# To find a solution to the problem with LEFT JOIN's IN in SQL

Tags: sql, database

**How can you have `IN` -clause in `ON` -clause with `LEFT JOIN`?**

I am trying to select the title of a question, tag(s) for the question and question_id for the question from my [database](http://dpaste.com/80758/) such that question_id is `14`. I expect to the tags and title of the question with question_id 14.

The output should look like

```
title       |         question_id        |        tag
------------|----------------------------|-----------------
A           |         14                 |        php     
A           |         14                 |        perl
A           |         14                 |        sql
A           |         14                 |        databases
```

The problem is actually slightly more challenging than initially.

*[SQL command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280251/to-put-an-array-to-a-where-clause-in-php-without-hitting-x-times-postgres/1280265#1280265)*

```
SELECT questions.title, questions.question_id, tags.tag
    FROM questions
    LEFT JOIN tags
    ON questions.question_id = tags.question_id IN (     // Problem here!
           SELECT question_id 
           FROM questions 
           DESC LIMIT 50 )
    WHERE questions.question_id = 14
    ORDER BY was_sent_at_time
    DESC LIMIT 50;
```

**Thanks to Joe and Tchami in solving the first problem!**

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve now? Having that IN clause shouldn't be necessary. What output do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280888/to-get-many-tags-for-a-question-effectively-from-postgres-by-php is based on the problems here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified the join condition for the second table, so you are selecting every tag for every title.

Use WHERE for the row condition

How are the two tables related? Add that condition to the join. For example

```
SELECT questions.title, questions.question_id, tags.tag
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN tags
ON questions.question_id = tags.question_id
WHERE questions.question_id = 14
ORDER BY was_sent_at_time
DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Thank you for solving the first problem! - I updated my question to show the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT questions.title, questions.question_id, tags.tag
    FROM questions
    LEFT JOIN tags
    ON questions.question_id = tags.question_id
    WHERE questions.question_id = 14
    ORDER BY was_sent_at_time
    DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Here's an [article](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) on how left join works.

You're missing the information on how the two tables should be joined, i.e.:

```
ON questions.question_id = tags.question_id
```

And after that you specify which question_id you want:

```
WHERE questions.question_id = 14
```

Comment: Thank you for solving the first problem! - I updated my question to show the actual problem.