# To get many tags for a question effectively from Postgres by PHP

Tags: php, database, postgresql

**How can you get many tags for a question effectively from [Postgres database](http://dpaste.com/80758/) by PHP?**

I have tables *tags* and *questions* where I have the variables `questions_question_id` and `question_id`, respectively, for instance.

One question may have many tags.
I can select `question_id`, `title` and a `tag` from the tables. 
However, I do not know **how to get many tags for one question out of the database effectively.** PHP restricts me in manipulating the data as matrices.

I can read question_id, title and tag to the variable $result.
The data is a matrix for me in the variale $result.
However, I cannot refer to the data like to a matrix.

I have only found the functions `pg_fetch_row` and `pg_fetch_all_columns` in PHP. The former gets the data as arrays for rows, while the latter as arrays for columns.

My problem with [LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280721/to-find-a-solution-to-the-problem-with-left-joins-in-in-sql) suggests me that it may not be possible to get the data as follows

1. get the columns for *title, question_id* and *tag*
2. group the data by question_id such that I can put tags to my questions: I have tried to manipulate the data by PHP, but I get only [this far](http://dpaste.com/80765/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a second query that gets all the tags for a given question. Trying to join them together is gonna be cumbersome. It can be done but you'll end up with several rows with the same question data but different tag data.

So first do something like this (I don't know the structure of your database so this is just an example):

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE ID = <id>;
```

Then you do a query right after that one, which asks for all the tags:

```
SELECT * FROM TAGS WHERE QUESTION_ID = <question_id>;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are bold, you can implement an aggregate function in PostgreSQL which concatenates all the relevant tags together for you, and then a single query will *Do What You Want (tm)*.

```
pg=> create aggregate ARRAY_ACCUM (
  sfunc = array_append,
  basetype = anyelement,
  stype = anyarray,
  initcond = '{}'
);

pg=> select QUESTIONS.ID as "QID",
pg-> array_to_string(array_accum(TAG), ',') as "TAGS"
pg-> from QUESTIONS
pg->   left join TAGS on QUESTIONS.ID = TAGS.QID;
 QID |     TAGS      
-----+---------------
   1 | foo, bar, baz
   2 | foo, bar
   3 | foo
   4 | 

-- Reference, for completeness --
pg=> select * from QUESTIONS;
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
(4 rows)

pg=> select * from TAGS;
 qid | tag 
-----+-----
   1 | foo
   1 | bar
   1 | baz
   2 | foo
   2 | bar
   3 | foo
```

Under MySQL, this functionality is called `GROUP_CONCAT`.  Under pg, it's called "Do It Yourself." :)  Now, there are even subtler ways to go about it under pg, too.  Check out this [clever blog post](http://mssql-to-postgresql.blogspot.com/2007/12/cool-groupconcat.html), and its comments, from which I stole^Wadapted the `create aggregate` solution proposed above. :)

Comment: This solution likely has one great disadvantage. If you make a search which need to process tags such that it can show questions with the given tag, then I see that this solution will hit a lot database.

Comment: @Masi, it's difficult to refute speculative performance concerns without so much as pseudocode.  I'd encourage you to `EXPLAIN` and to *profile* any proposed solution. :)